# Set Default landing page

Tags: lightning, landing-page

I created my own custom app, now I need to set this app as the default landing app. In Salesforce Classic I went to *Profile -> App -> Custom App* but when I logged in after I switched in lightning, I ended up in the Setup Tab. Why? How I can set the custom app as the default app also in lightning?

Comment: Did you try with another profile other than sys admin?

Answer (score 1):

with the help from my colleagues I found a solution. In lightning in the user interface you must un-check a chekbox that says:

> set Setup my default landing page.

If this check is true you always end up in setup despite the default app you set.

Answer (score 0):

In lightning you would have to go to: `Setup> Apps> App Manager`, and then create a Lightning app. In the wizard you'll see you can configure mostly everything, including which profiles will have access to it.

I hope it is useful!

Answer (score 0):

Default app configuration comes from Profile. But if a profile have access to multiple App Salesforce remembers which one the last app being used by the user.

For example "Sales" is the default app for Sysadmin profile and it has also access to custom app "APP ONE" now if you are in sales app in classic view whenever you login in classic you will see sales app landing page after login.

Now you switched to lightning and gone to "App ONE" and log out when you log back in you will go to "App One" landing page.

Now you switched to classic you will go to Sales landing page - Salesforce remembered your choice.

Now you switch your view to lightning you will go to "App One" home page

So the landing page will be same if you have access to only one app in classic and lightning.

Salesforce remembers in which APP you left your classic app as well as your Lightning app.

Hope this answers your question.